# how to convert database table values to array string?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to read the values from the database and convert it to a string array.

```
strQ = "SELECT * FROM Courses"
cmd = New SqlCommand(strQ, conn)
da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
ds = New DataSet
da.Fill(ds, "Courses")

Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim j As Integer = 0

For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
    Me.ListView1.Columns.Add(ds.Tables(0).Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString())
Next
For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1   

  For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1 
    itemcol(j) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j).ToString()
  Next

  Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(itemcol)
  Me.ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
Next
```

I want to convert it to array format.

Edit from comments: Basically we're are dealing with courses and the number of students. The numbers are the student IDs who are taking the course. Here's some sample data:

```
jb(0) = {1,2,3,4,5} 'CIT121
jb(1) = {1,2,6,7,8} 'CIT141 
jb(2) = {6,7,8,15,16} 'CIT202 
jb(3) = {4,10,11} 'CIT203
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mentioned code

```
For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
     ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).ItemArray.[Select](Function(x) x.ToString()).ToArray()
Next
```